# SQL query Question

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I'm currently learning SQL and have some issues figuring how to do the following:

Tables:

```
Planned Order
    id  Item    Date
    0   1   2011-01-24
    1   1   2011-01-26
    2   1   2011-01-28
    3   2   2011-01-24
    4   3   2011-01-27

Customer Order
    id  Item    Date
    4   2   2011-01-25
    3   2   2011-01-24
    2   2   2011-01-24
    1   1   2011-01-26
    0   1   2011-01-24
```

I'm trying to produce the following query that will produce:

```
Item  Category          2011-01-24      2011-01-25   2011-01-26   
1     Customer_Order    1               NULL         1      
1     Planned_Order     1               NULL         1
2     Customer_Order    2               NULL         NULL
2     Planned_Order     1               NULL         NULL
3     Planned_Order     NULL            NULL         NULL
```

Where the count under the date is how many times the item was ordered that day.

Is this even possible with raw sql code or is this?  I realize this can be done through other languages such as perl to manipulate the data and through multiple data base access, but I wanted to do this directly from raw sql.

I can't find a command(raw sql) to convert a query from a column and convert it to a row.  How I query the dates and produce column for each date like seen above.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL or something else?

Comment: In addition to Drackir's question, do you have .NET or any other programming language that you're using? You may have to get your results and format them to the layout you need.

Comment: I don't know an exact answer, because creating dynamic columns out of row values (date in this case) is a tough job that needs a different solution on each database, but you should at least Google for `pivot table`.

Comment: I'm trying to give someone raw sql so that they can run on a sql analyzer, so i'm assuming sql server.  Currently thou, i'm testing with mysql.  Btw: Is there a way protable version of sql

Comment: Can't provide a dynamic pivot answer till the DB is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

In Sql Server (2005/2008), there´s an operator to do exactly what you need (PIVOT)

```
SELECT Item,Category,[2011-01-24], [2011-01-25], [2011-01-26]
FROM
(SELECT Item, 'Planned_Order' Category, Date
 FROM   [Planned Order]
 union all
 SELECT Item, 'Customer_Order', Date
 FROM   [Customer Order]
 ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
COUNT(*)
FOR Date IN ([2011-01-24], [2011-01-25], [2011-01-26])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: what happens if you don't know the dates off bat and need to dynamically query the distinct dates in a table?  How would you specify the subquery into categories for the main query?

Comment: Basically in that case you have to dynamically build the query using something like: select @dates = @dates+','+Date from Table group by Date and concatenate it with the rest of the query

Comment: can you be more detailed with 'select @dates = @dates+','+Date ' I can grab the dates with a select statement but not sure how to store all the values.....do arrays exist in sql?  Thanks!

Comment: You don´t need an array, all values are been concatenated into @dates variable, separated by a comma that´s all what you need

Comment: but if you don't know how many dates there are, how would u know how many variables to declare if your dynamically grabbing it from a query where the size can change.  Each @variable can only store one value.

Comment: No, @Variable is a string that can contain more than one value, separated by commas. (For example @Value='[2011-01-24], [2011-01-25], [2011-01-26], [2011-01-27]') That´s exactly what you nedd to compose the above query.

Answer (score 1):

Portable way to do Pivoting:

```
select item, 'Customer_Order' Category,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-24' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-24`,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-25' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-25`,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-26' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-26`
from customer_order
GROUP BY item
union all
select item, 'Planned_Order' Category,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-24' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-24`,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-25' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-25`,
  COUNT(case when Date='2011-01-26' then 1 else 0 end) as `2010-01-26`
from planned_order
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY item, Category
```

The problem is that you need to know all the dates you want to display up front. The only DBMS (I know of) to support a dynamic list of columns is Oracle. Other DBMS will require you to generate dynamic SQL to create the CASE statements, one for each distinct date encountered.

The only non-portable part is that because of using dates as field names, you need

```
`2010-01-24` backticks here for MySQL
"2010-01-24" or [2010-01-24] for SQL Server
"2010-01-24" for Oracle
etc
```